# How to extract part of string in WIX bootstrapper

Tags: outlook, wix

I need to extract a piece of a string from a value I get by the registry search in WIX. Following is the overall outline of what I am trying to do.

```
  <util:RegistrySearch Id="RegSearch" 
                     Root="HKCR" 
                     Key="Outlook.Application\CurVer" 
                     Format="raw"
                     Variable="version"/>

  <util:RegistrySearch Id="RegSearch2" 
                     Root="HKLM" 
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\[version].0\Outlook" 
                     Value="Bitness"
                     Format="raw"
                     Variable="Bit"/>
```

The second registry search do not work because the result produced by [version] looks something like "Applicaiton.Outlook.xx". How can I only extract only the xx part from "Applicaiton.Outlook.xx" resulted in [version] property, so i can use that value in the second registry search ? Code examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be overcome by creating a custom action. Define a property and as the value, call the custom action. Within the custom action callback method we can read registry and get the sub-string and assign the required value to the property.